# Raise Property Changed event from other class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, propertychanged

In my project I want to display a List on a user control. For that I have a CategoryView the user control with an ListView-control, where I want to display the List. And the CategoryViewModel. On the ViewModel I have a list - property where I also raise the property changed event.

```
public class CategoryViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private List<string> categoryList;

    public List<string> CategoryList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.categoryList;
        }
        set
        {
            this.categoryList = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryList");
        }
    }
}
```

This List is binded to the ListView-element in the view.

If I change the List in the CategoryViewModel, it works fine and the property change event is raised. If I change the List from the MainWindowViewModel. No property Changed event is Raised and the View will not be updated. How do I have to do that?

On the MainWindowViewModel I change the CategoryList. The List will be filled correctly.

```
CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
categoryViewModel.CategoryList = logger.ReadLogfile(this.logFileName).ToList();
```

Comment: can you add the xaml you use to bind to this list? I'm going to assume you have a property in your MainViewModel that you set to = this categoryViewModel? The code you have shown is creating a new CategoryViewModel and setting it's CategoryList to values from the file. If you aren't setting the MainViewModels CategoryViewModel property to = this new one, that would be the problem.

Comment: Have you double checked that the Category view model you update in the Main Window View Model is ***the same instance*** that is bound to the UI of your user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be somewhat confused. You have one `ListView` in your `CategoryView UserControl`. Its `ItemsSource` property can *only* be data bound to one collection, so clearly, when changing the collections in the main view model *and* the `CategoryViewModel`, only one will affect the `ListView`.

It seems from your code that the `CategoryViewModel` is set as the `DataContext` for the `UserControl`, so the collection in the main view model will not be connected to the `ListView`. If you want to data bind from the `ListView` to the collection in the main view model instead, then you'll need to use a `RelativeSource Binding` instead:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourParentType}}}" ... />
```

Even so, now the collection in your `CategoryViewModel` will no longer be connected, so you'd better decide exactly what you want to do here.